# Setup Alfa AWUS036NHR V2 to Kali Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, kali-linux

I downloaded driver for this from official site. Unzipped the archive, make install.sh executable and try execute. But error is occured - No rule to build the target modules. Stop. I executed commands below, which found with google:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

prepare-kernel-sources
```

And error occured - command not found...

In manufacturer guide (http://www.alfa.com.tw/press_c_show.php?sn=5):

> 4.If you receive a makefile error about “no rule to make target modules”, you may need to prepare kernel headers. As root, at the
>   command line run these commands (you will need to have Internet access
>   on the computer already):
>
> ```
> prepare-kernel-sources
> cd /usr/src/linux
> cp -rf include/generated/* include/linux/
> ```

But it doesn't work.